# quotient of an affine variety and action of a finite group: $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}_n$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to solve exercise 2.6.4 from the script by Gathmann on algebraic geometry from 2002/03-

Let $\mathbb{Z}_n$ denote the group of $n^{th}$ unit roots in $\mathbb{C}$ acting on $\mathbb{C}$. It must be shown that $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

$\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}_n$ is considered a quotient of the affine variety $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_n$. My interpretation of $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}_n$ was that the equivalence classes of an element $a$ of $\mathbb{C}$ are the rotations of $a$ by elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: How do I show this isomorphism?

Comment: Try mapping the equivalence class of $a$ to $a^n\in\mathbb{C}$.